# Python: can a class instance evaluate to any type?

Tags: python, class, tuples

A class can act as a string through its __str__ method, or as a function via its __call__ method. Can it act as, say, a list, or a tuple?

```
class A (object):
    def __???__ (self):
        return (1, 2, 3)

>>> a = A()
>>> a * 3
(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3)
```

**EDIT...**

Here's a better example to help clarify the above.

```
class Vector (object):
    def __init__ (self):
        self.vec = (1,2,3)
    def __???__ (self):
        # something like __repr__; non-string
        return self.vec

class Widget (object):
    def __init__ (self):
        self.vector = Vector()

>>> w = Widget()
>>> w.vector
(1, 2, 3) # not a string representation (at least, before being repr'd here)
```

Basically, I want something like __repr__ that doesn't return a string, but returns a tuple (or list) when I simply invoke the name pointing to the Vector instance, but I don't want to lose the rest of the abilities in the instance, like access to other properties and methods. I also don't want to have to use `w.vector.vec` to get to the data. I want vector to act like a tuple attribute of w, while still being able to do something like `w.vector.whatever()`, or overriding __mul__ so I can scale the vector via `w.vector * 5`. Possible?

Comment: The class doesn't act as a string when you call `__str__` it creates and returns a NEW string object. I don't really see what your getting at...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on what your goal is, you can create a class that inherits from built-in classes like `list` or `tuple`:

```
>>> class A(tuple):
...     def speak(self):
...         print "Bark!"
... 
>>> a = A((1,2,3)) # extra parens needed to distinguish single tuple arg from 3 scalar args
>>> a * 3
(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3)
>>> a.speak()
Bark!
```

Given your Vector use case, subclassing tuple might well do the trick.

```
import math

class Vector(tuple):
    def magnitude(self):
        return math.sqrt( self[0]*self[0]+self[1]*self[1]+self[2]*self[2] )
```

Comment: I'm going to have a test a bit, but I think this is the answer. I basically want a tuple that I can do other things with/to, like add properties and methods, and access them, but if I just use *it* anywhere, I want it to "be" a tuple.

Comment: What's your larger goal? You might want Panda3D or something.

Comment: That's funny. We actually use Panda at my company. My goal is to be able to have something like vectors as constant-like properties of certain class instances, which can be accessed very easily as instance properties (i.e. w.vector), scaled simply (e.g. `w.vector*3` scales each component), and manipulated in many other ways with custom methods (e.g. w.vector.inWorld()). I also want these properties to be able to serve up further information about themselves(e.g. w.vector.property).

Comment: @GaryFixler: Are you sure you don't want to subclass something like `numpy.array()` instead of a plain Python `tuple` or `list`?

Comment: I'm not sure about that, as I have not looked into numpy. However, if I go with numpy, it means further R&D time, and the need to deploy it as part of a toolchain, which lessens the ROI a bit. My needs are quite simple here.

Comment: The main reason to use `numpy` is that it already implements matrix math (a la MATLAB). If you're dealing with numerical computation, you want to use `numpy` - this will almost certainly *reduce* your development time.

Comment: I'll add it to the big stack of things to look into as soon as possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For the specific behaviour in your example (`A*3` gives three concatenated copies of the data in `A`) you want to implement the `__mul__()` operator.

For example, these are equivalent:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> a*3
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
>>> a.__mul__(3)
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
>>>
```

More generally, if you want to implement a sequence type you have to implement all of the [operations defined for sequence types](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/ref/sequence-types.html). You have to define -

- what `A[3]` means (`__getitem__()`, `__setitem__()`)
- what `A[1:10]` means (`__getslice__()`)
- what `for item in A:` means (`__iter__()`)

and so on.

Here's the full list of methods defined on `list`s:

```
>>> pprint.pprint(dict(list.__dict__))
{'__add__': <slot wrapper '__add__' of 'list' objects>,
 '__contains__': <slot wrapper '__contains__' of 'list' objects>,
 '__delitem__': <slot wrapper '__delitem__' of 'list' objects>,
 '__delslice__': <slot wrapper '__delslice__' of 'list' objects>,
 '__doc__': "list() -> new empty list\nlist(iterable) -> new list initialized from iterable's items",
 '__eq__': <slot wrapper '__eq__' of 'list' objects>,
 '__ge__': <slot wrapper '__ge__' of 'list' objects>,
 '__getattribute__': <slot wrapper '__getattribute__' of 'list' objects>,
 '__getitem__': <method '__getitem__' of 'list' objects>,
 '__getslice__': <slot wrapper '__getslice__' of 'list' objects>,
 '__gt__': <slot wrapper '__gt__' of 'list' objects>,
 '__hash__': None,
 '__iadd__': <slot wrapper '__iadd__' of 'list' objects>,
 '__imul__': <slot wrapper '__imul__' of 'list' objects>,
 '__init__': <slot wrapper '__init__' of 'list' objects>,
 '__iter__': <slot wrapper '__iter__' of 'list' objects>,
 '__le__': <slot wrapper '__le__' of 'list' objects>,
 '__len__': <slot wrapper '__len__' of 'list' objects>,
 '__lt__': <slot wrapper '__lt__' of 'list' objects>,
 '__mul__': <slot wrapper '__mul__' of 'list' objects>,
 '__ne__': <slot wrapper '__ne__' of 'list' objects>,
 '__new__': <built-in method __new__ of type object at 0x1E1DACA8>,
 '__repr__': <slot wrapper '__repr__' of 'list' objects>,
 '__reversed__': <method '__reversed__' of 'list' objects>,
 '__rmul__': <slot wrapper '__rmul__' of 'list' objects>,
 '__setitem__': <slot wrapper '__setitem__' of 'list' objects>,
 '__setslice__': <slot wrapper '__setslice__' of 'list' objects>,
 '__sizeof__': <method '__sizeof__' of 'list' objects>,
 'append': <method 'append' of 'list' objects>,
 'count': <method 'count' of 'list' objects>,
 'extend': <method 'extend' of 'list' objects>,
 'index': <method 'index' of 'list' objects>,
 'insert': <method 'insert' of 'list' objects>,
 'pop': <method 'pop' of 'list' objects>,
 'remove': <method 'remove' of 'list' objects>,
 'reverse': <method 'reverse' of 'list' objects>,
 'sort': <method 'sort' of 'list' objects>}
```

Comment: I know about the \_\_mul\_\_ operator, and will be implementing it for this need. However, in my example I was just trying to show that it was indeed returning a tuple, and not a string representation of a tuple. It's getting a simple usage of a class to act like a type, while still retaining other abilities, like calling methods that I'm interested in. Maybe I can subclass tuple somehow?

Comment: @GaryFixler: If you want to be able to cast the object to a tuple, you need to make the object "iterable". (remember the `TypeError: 'A' object is not iterable` error? That's what it's talking about.) Implementing `__iter__()` should be sufficient to do that. Then `tuple(A)`, which expands to `tuple(A.__iter__())`, should do what you want. Likewise,  loops over `A` will work, list comprehensions will work, and so on.

Comment: @Li-aungYip note that you don't need to implement `__setitem__` as part of the sequence protocol (unless you explicitly want it to be mutable, in which case you want to implement `__delitem__`, `insert` and others as well), and `__{get,set,del}slice__` has been deprecated for a while in favour of passing a `slice` object to `__{get,set,del}item__`. The best and easiest way for a class to implement the full sequence protocol is to inherit from `collections.Sequence` (or, `collections.abc.Sequence` from 3.3). (unless it makes sense to inherit from an existing sequence type, of course).

Comment: @lvc: Thanks for that. I forgot to mention that a *sequence* type really only needs to be iterable. `get*` and `set*` are only needed to random access to elements. Good information about `collections.Sequence` as well, thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

The class doesn't act as a string when you call **str**. It creates and returns a NEW string object. Basically when you call `str(something)` on an object, this is what really happens:

```
a = str(someObject)

a = someObject.__str__()
```

So the `str` function can basically be thought of as doing this:

```
def str(variable):
    return variable.__str__()
```

The same is true when you call `list()`, `tuple()`, `set()` and so on. If what I think you're asking is correct:

`tuple()`, `list()`, and `set()` all call the `__iter__()` method of a class, so what you'd want to do is:

```
class MyClass(object):
    ...
    def __iter__(self):
        ...
        return myIterable
```

Comment: I understand that it's creating and returning a string, but to me, that fits the definition of a class acting as a string. I don't know how it would work otherwise. \_\_iter\_\_ is the closest I've come to an answer so far, but it still requires extra work, like calling iter on it. Maybe I don't have the problem defined well enough in my head yet.

Comment: @GaryFixler: You don't have to call `__iter__()`. Using an instance of `A` any place that requires an iterable type will call `__iter__()` implicitly. For example the loop `for item in A:` is syntax sugar for `for item in A.__iter__():`. So if you define `__iter__()`, that's enough to be able to cast instance of `A` to lists, or use them like lists (though if you want to implement random access, you will have to implement `__setitem__()` and `__getitem__()` too.)

Comment: @GaryFixler: It doesn't require extra work. `list(myObject)` implicitly calls myObject.__iter__(), as does any expression that requires an iterator.

Comment: @JoelCornett: The hand is quicker than the eye!

Comment: The tricky bit is that I'd like it to work outside of places where iterators are presumed. For example, assignment. I can get something very much like what I want with instance attributes by overriding them with \_\_getattr\_\_. I want something like that ability with the instance itself, so anywhere it's accessed, e.g. during assignment to another variable, a tuple is returned and used instead. Then I *still* want to be able to access the bits inside the class, if I dot on something like a property or method identifier. This may not be possible, but I had to ask.

Comment: @GaryFixler: Why don't you subclass tuple?

Comment: @JoelCornett - I believe that's what I'm going to be doing. Thanks.